# WaitForMultipleObjects For Stack

Tags: c, windows, stack

You know that `WaitForMultipleObjects` funtction from windows library in c is getting parameter as an array for objects. But in my homework, assistant wants to keep all the threads in a stack not in an array how can i use this function with a stack?

Comment: A stack is a particularly unsuitable data structure to store threads.  Thread behavior is not at all stack-like, they complete at non-deterministic times.  Fix the data structure, fixes your problem too.

Comment: What exactly is meant here by a stack? Do you mean parameters of a function? Because, you know, a simple array is on a stack as well.

Comment: Create a temporary array, copy the handles from the stack to the array, pass the temporary array to `WaitForMultipleObjects`. Classic example of the [adapter pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can only call this function with an array. That is not something you have any control over. So you need to use a stack that is capable of exposing its contents as an array. Or an array that is capable of operating like a stack.

However, it is perfectly plausible that the use of a stack container for your threads is simply inappropriate. Why does your homework assistant want to use a stack?

Comment: @alk perfectly plausible in C also

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean the sequence of entry objects for `WaitForMultipleObjects` is important?

There is no difference between sorted sequence of the entry objects and random sequence of them for this function.

In addition, in many implementations a stack is an array and you can pass the pointer of that array to this function.

Answer (score 1):

If there's a fixed order in which threads complete and you want to wait for them to complete one by one, a stack kind of makes sense.

Suppose you have 3 threads and their handles are stored in an array:

```
HANDLE handles[3];
```

Now, if you do `WaitForMultipleObjects(3, handles, FALSE /* bWaitAll */, INFINITE)`, it will return when the first thread completes. If you invoke WaitForMultipleObjects() with those same parameters again, it won't wait for the next thread's completion. It will fail. To wait for the remaining threads you will have to exclude the completed thread's handle from the array.

If threads complete in the fixed order of 2, 1, 0 you can wait like this:

```
WaitForMultipleObjects(3, handles, FALSE /* bWaitAll */, INFINITE);
WaitForMultipleObjects(2, handles, FALSE /* bWaitAll */, INFINITE);
WaitForMultipleObjects(1, handles, FALSE /* bWaitAll */, INFINITE);
```

as if you were calling WaitForMultipleObjects() on a stack, popping a handle off it after each call to WaitForMultipleObjects().

Comment: +1, you're most likely limiting the amount of threads you can/will spawn so representing the stack as array + index is the simplest solution

Answer (score 0):

I probably don't understand the question, because my answer is what I usually do anyway:

```
HANDLE threads[2]; // On stack, as opposed to new HANDLE[2]
unsigned threadID;

threads[0] = (HANDLE)_beginthreadex(NULL, 0, &OneThreadFunc, NULL, 0, &threadID);
threads[1] = (HANDLE)_beginthreadex(NULL, 0, &AnotherThreadFunc, NULL, 0, &threadID);

WaitForMultipleObjects(threads, _countof(threads), TRUE, INFINITE);
```